# Why is the Scala compiler giving me an error when passing a Kotlin sealed class into a constructor?

Tags: scala, jvm, kotlin, scalac

I have a sealed class, written in Kotlin:

```
sealed class Schema {
    class RecordSchema(val fields: List<Field>): Schema()
    class ArraySchema(val elementSchema: Schema): Schema()
    ...
}
```

And another class that takes `RecordSchema` as a parameter:

`class Enrichment(config: Config, val schema: RecordSchema) { ... }`

In Scala I have a class that, among other things, get an instance of the `RecordSchema` and then create an instance of the `Enrichment`.

```
object Job {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        /// some initializing of resources... and then...
        val recordSchema = schemas.getSchema(id) // type is Schema.RecordSchema
        val enrichment = Enrichment(config, recordSchema) // this is where scalac errors out
    }
}
```

The scala compiler ends up printing this error message:

```
Error:(52, 62) type mismatch;
 found   : com.companyname.enricher.schemas.com.companyname.enricher.schemas.com.companyname.enricher.schemas.
 required: com.companyname.enricher.schemas.(some other)com.companyname.enricher.schemas.com.companyname.enricher.schemas.
    val enrichment = new Enrichment(config, recordSchema)
```

If I cast `recordSchema` using `asInstanceOf` I get another, not so useful, error:

```
Error:(52, 62) type mismatch;
 found   : com.companyname.enricher.schemas.Schema.RecordSchema
 required: com.companyname.enricher.schemas.com.companyname.enricher.schemas.
    val enrichment = new Enrichment(config, recordSchema.asInstanceOf[RecordSchema])
```

Overall, I have no idea why this is happening.  If I make the constructor take the parent class as a parameter rather than nested class, it compiles just fine (which is my workaround for now).  If I do the same type of thing, except having written the sourcecode in Java rather than Kotlin, this error does not happen.  I am using Java 1.8, Kotlin 1.0.4, Scala 2.11.8.

UPDATE:

demonstrated bug here:
https://github.com/mjburghoffer/scala-kotlin-innerclass-bug/tree/master

Comment: I will guess that you need `val recordSchema:Schema = schemas.getSchema(id)`, does that work?

Comment: No, that moves the compiler error to that statement, which a similar error message to the second error.

Comment: can you the declaration of `schemas` and the implementation (or at least method signature) of `schemas.getSchema(id)` ?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I am just wrapping a schema registry library.  Trying to reduce the amount of noise in the original post - the signature is simply `fun getSchema(id: Int): Schema.RecordSchema`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Kotlin generates different number of classes for this case. I compiled Java and Kotlin sources and found that Java has additional file `ParentSealedJava$1.class`. Bytecode of `Parent` and `Sealed` classes in Java and Kotlin pretty the same (i inspect bytecode using javap -c), so i think Scala compiler relies somehow on this missing file in Kotlin.

Comment: Yeah not sure if it's a bug in Kotlin or Scala or both, but ultimately this looks like a bug.  Submitted to both Scala and Kotlin teams - we'll see if a fix pans out.

Comment: Since Kotlin classes works in Java i think this is bug in scalac.